# Populate Dropdwon with DIR files, save value and keep it "selected"

Tags: admin, plugin-options

i have a dropdown list which gets populated by the content of a folder. When i save the page, the dropdown resets and does not show the selected image.
Other options on the same page (color/text..) do save and keep the value.

Any ideas? I've tried with the "selected" function but it does not work in the way i used it.

Thanks everyone!

**Code:**

```
/*create the field*/

add_settings_field( 
    'psg_dyn_select_1', 
    __( 'Settings field description', 'wordpress' ), 
    'psg_dyn_select_1_render', 
    'pluginPage', 
    'psg_pluginPage_section' 
);

/*output the field*/

function psg_dyn_select_1_render ( ) {

$options = get_option( 'psg_settings' );
?>
<select name= 'psg_settings[psg_dyn_select_1]'>
   <?php foreach ( glob( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "assets/images/*" ) as $filename){
   $filename = basename($filename);
   echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename." </option>";}?>     
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a 'selected' value to the option output, so that the html displays the value that's saved in the psg_settings.

Something like this:

```
function psg_dyn_select_1_render ( ) {
    $options = get_option( 'psg_settings' );
    $files = glob( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "assets/images/*" );
    ?>
    <select name= 'psg_settings[psg_dyn_select_1]'>
    <?php foreach ($files as $filename){
        $filename = basename($filename);
        $selected = ($filename == $options['psg_dyn_select_1']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
        echo "<option value='" . $filename . "' " . 
            $selected . ">".$filename." </option>";
    }?> 
    </select>
}
```

If that's not working, then you need to debug what the value of `$options` and `$options['psg_dyn_select_1']` are in comparison to what's being output in your select dropdown (the values of `$filename`).